# Does this riddle have coordinates in it?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

I have been given this riddle that is supposed to revel a location:

You might disagree, but invite them anyways; you can at least talk it out.[A drum of what follows a copy / Foxtrot10 Yankee1 alfa11 Hotel110 xray111 Whiskey100 Three101 golf1000]

My question can the military alphabet correlate to coordinates?

I have tried using the letter positions in the alphabet but it doesn't seem to add up.

Any ideas?

## Update

I also think that it might not be physical coordinates but a web address of some sort.

I think the call signs might refer to binary but haven't worked out what yet.

Something like this maybe:
F10 Y1 a11 H110 x111 W100 [T/3]101 g1000

Comment: Hi jmartin and welcome to Puzzling :) Please could you tell us the source for this puzzle - who set it or where did you find it - so its creator can be acknowledged (it's our site policy)? Thanks!